# Memory pool management in C

Tags: c, memory-management

I am implementing my own memory pool in C and I am having a problem with finding out how many bytes the block of memory pointed to by *ptr is (size_t poolSize(void *ptr)). The code is just to show part of what I have and where the problem is, I know I have to deal with alignment and some other stuffs. I am also new to C which I am self-learning so I'm still learning how pointers work (my problem might be with pointers).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct NODE MemPool;

struct NODE
{
  char * next;
  char * end;
};

MemPool * poolCreate( size_t size )
{
    MemPool * newPool = (MemPool *)malloc( size + sizeof(MemPool) );
    newPool->next = (char*)&newPool[1];
    newPool->end = newPool->next + size;

    return newPool;
}

void * poolAlloc( MemPool *pool, size_t size )
{
    void *result = NULL;

    if( (pool->end - pool->next) < size )
        return NULL;

    result = (void *)pool->next;
    pool->next += size;

    return result;
}

size_t poolSize(void *ptr)
{
    return ((size_t)&ptr);
}

void poolDestroy( MemPool *pool )
{
    free(pool);
}
```

Comment: What does `ptr` point to when `poolSize` is called? Does it point to a pool? Or to an allocation that came from the pool? Or what?

Comment: You're casting a pointer to `size_t` which is very probably very wrong. Perhaps you wanted to cast the pointer to `size_t*` *and* dereference it?

Comment: Where do you keep data? The NODE struct does not have a place for it. Further, do not calculate sizes. Add a member holding the size to your NODE struct

Comment: Consider adding a header (or add to your NODE struct) that contains the length of the chunk you're dealing with.

Comment: You should add an executable example that manifests the problem, if you do it would be solved in less than an hour.

Answer (score 1):

> how many bytes the block of memory pointed to by *ptr

No, you don't have a standard way to find the size of allocated memory from the pointer itself. You have to keep track of the size yourself when you are doing `malloc`. or you have to store the size of the allocated memory in another variable.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly you want to do by the code, but result is next:
1.

```
MemPool * newPool = (MemPool *)malloc( size + sizeof(MemPool) );
```

allocate memory:

```
[[ sizeof(MemPool) ][ size ]]
^
|
newPool
```

2.

```
newPool->next = (char*)&newPool[1];
```

set 'next' pointer to [size] part of the allocated memory:

```
[[ sizeof(MemPool) ][ size ]]
^                   ^
|                   |
newPool             newPool->next
```

3.

```
newPool->end = newPool->next + size;
```

set 'end' pointer to end of the allocated memory:

```
[[ sizeof(MemPool) ][ size      ]]
^                   ^             ^
|                   |             |
newPool             newPool->next newPool->end
```

Maybe 'next' should point to some next pool node? If it is a pointer to custom memory then it useless due may be always calculated as:

```
... = newPool + 1;
```

Size of custom memory may be calculated as:

```
... = newPool->end - (char*)(newPool + 1);
```

According to

```
size_t poolSize(void *ptr)
```

you cannot get size of the memory just by void pointer. If it is a pointer to part of pool node then start of the node may be found as:

```
MemPool * pool = (MemPool*)(ptr) - 1;
```

and then used 'end' pointer find destination size.

Answer (score 0):

This is an ambitious project for a beginner. Probably the best advice I could give would be to find an implementation written by someone else and study it until you understand it.

The answer to your question requires a cast. Assuming that `ptr` is a void pointer to the base of the arena block:

```
size_t poolSize(void *ptr) {
    MemPool* pool = (MemPool*)ptr;
    return (size_t)(pool->next - (char*)ptr);
}
```

Hope it helps.